# Long running VBA macros are interrupted by svchost.exe

Tags: excel, vba, windows, com

I have some Excel VBA macros that run for hours. The macros do millions of COM calls to get some information from a CAD application, crunch some numbers, then other millions of COM calls to the same CAD application to create some drawings. The macros write the status and the progress on a text file every second.

I have a Python process that checks whether the progress file has been updated in the last few seconds, and if it is not it will kill Excel and the CAD and notify of the failure.

The problem is that every 10 or 20 minutes I see an svchost.exe process in the task manager that takes 100% of a core for a few seconds, Excel CPU usage goes down to zero and most (not all) applications become not responsive. When svchost.exe goes back to 0%, Excel restarts running and continues its job.

Everything has worked well for years, but recently we started working with larger drawings and the svchost.exe started keeping Excel in hostage for longer and longer.

I increased the timeout from 20 seconds to 40, then to 60. But I just had a few instances where svchost.exe takes longer than a minute to do whatever it does.

If I right click on the svchost.exe process on the task manager, then on "go to services", I see two highlighted services: "RPC Endpoint Mapper" and "Remote Procedure Call (RPC)".

I have tried to add a 3 second pause every 10 seconds, hoping that svchost.exe would take advantage of the free time, but it didn't help.

The pauses appear to happen at random moments, usually when Excel loads data into a large collection, sometimes 2 or 3 times while the collection grows in size, or when the large collection goes out of scope.

I don't like to increase a timeout without knowing the reason and what is a good value.

Is there a way to avoid these long pauses?

Comment: (1) Why the close vote? 
(2) Why would you vote for closing without leaving a comment?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good time to consider limitations of using Excel for long-running processes.

Without seeing the code, all I can do is speculate that there's a memory leak in how the COM calls are processed. Perhaps Objects are not being properly disposed even with Set = Nothing ?

Could you consider re-writing the procedures in Python or VB.Net and taking advantage of the more effective trouble shooting / application design features?

I don't thin svchost.exe has anything to do with the crash, it might be represenative or symptomatic to the COM object's DLL interfaces? But not sure exactly without knowing what DLL's and Objects are used.

Comment: I would love to rewrite it in Python, but it's a 20 year old macro that grew up to 60,000 lines; rewriting it will take months. Can't do `Set = Nothing` because I'm adding objects to large collections to be sorted, processed and disposed at once in VBA. svchost.exe doesn't really cause a crash, it keeps the computer hostage for 60+ more seconds before giving the control back. Reducing one 60 second pause into 10 6 second pauses would be a good solution for me.

Comment: Is there a way to control the Input? It sounds like it worked when the objects were 'smaller' but recently you made the inputs 'bigger'.

Comment: A 20 year old Excel macro, wow. Maybe there have been several operating system and Excel changes? As for svchost, you get the impression it's used for everything and nothing. There seem to be a lot of objects that are managed. If they exist in collections, maybe it would be possible to use loops. I wonder if it would be possible to save the state of the macro at runtime when there are no problems yet and then restart the whole thing with the saved state. But honestly I have no idea how complex the implementation would be and if the knowledge for all parameters to be saved is available.

Comment: @Zwenn The larger the collection with COM objects, the longer the pauses with svchosts.exe. Smaller collections work because svchosts.exe takes over for just a few seconds. I can't predict when svchosts.exe is about to start, I haven't noticed any pattern. Instead of keeping a collection with some VBA native variables and some COM objects, I could keep only the VBA variables and the id of the CAD entities, then retrieve them when I need them later. This would more than double the time required for the whole job, but would likely fix my problem.

Comment: 'working with larger drawings' seems to be the key to your problem, can you split a drawing's input data into quarters and run across 4 different Excel Applications on separate machines? If the drawings are binary data or coordinates, this could work.

Comment: @Peyter The macro collects objects from the drawing, sorts them in different ways, looks for identical items, adds geometries to each item and creates new drawings. I need them all at once so I can sort and compare them all to each other. Thinking about Python, I am afraid that the problem would not be solved because I think it's caused by the way Windows manages COM objects, so I guess it doesn't matter whether the COM objects are collected by VBA or by Python.

Comment: @stenci I think you read informations like this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call Is the CAD file local or in the network? If in the network, try it with a local copy. By my knowlege svchost does something every time it's used in the internet or the LAN/ WLAN.

Comment: @Zwenn It is local.

Comment: @stenci That's hard :-/ I'm sorry, but my knowlege ends here

Comment: @stenci I hope you solve the problem. It seems like a big project and "sudden death" always sucks. (Sorry for wording.)

Comment: @Zwenn Sudden death sucks even more when it's not so sudden because it happens hours after your click!